# Export exponentiated coefficients from a logistic regression in R

Tags: r, latex, logistic-regression, fixest

I use `etable` to export my regression results to latex. Since I run a logistic regression (using fixest package), I would like to export exponentiated coefficients (odds ratios). In Stata I can simply type "or" at the end of a regression. How can I do this in R?

I tried `m1[["coefficients"]][["ln_gft"]] <- exp(m1[["coefficients"]][["ln_gft"]])` however this only affects the coefficients, not the standard errors.

Comment: Can you please make this into a reproducible example? (ie could you run a similar analysis on a standard data set, or provide some sample data?) We have no way to know what `m1` is here, so it will be hard for us to guess how to extract information from it.

Comment: Hmm. This is relatively easy with other model types and a different model stack (e.g. `glm` + `broom` + `modelsummary`: `tidy.glm()` has an `exponentiate` argument ...). I can tell you the math behind transforming SEs (multiply by the derivative of the inverse-link function evaluated at the coefficient estimate) - but I don't know what component of the model object you'd have to hack to make this work.